# What stops a hacker changing the last block?

Tags: blockchain

Say a hacker is tinkering with a receivers public key in the latest block in a chain such that they change it to their own public key and intercept the transaction. The verifying process is only between the signature and the sender's public key with no reference to the receivers public key.

The hacker could then mine the block (and potentially be first) to find the new hash. This means they gain their mining reward as well as intercepting bitcoin fraudulently.

Answer (score 6):

> The verifying process is only between the signature and the sender's public key with no reference to the receivers public key.

That's incorrect. The message signed by the sender includes several pieces of information, including the outputs of the transaction. Changing the receiver's public key would invalidate the signer's signature.

Comment: Thanks for correcting Pieter, looks like the Blockchain 101 video I watched was wrong... I thought the process of verifying was to compare the sender's public key with the signature and to ensure they both come from the same private key?

Comment: @Vik: a spender has to satisfy the locking script that is in *a prior block*